# Create a class with static and friend methods C++

Tags: c++, static-methods, friend

why would you create a class with only static and friends methods?

For example:

```
namespace Image
{
    GLuint LoadImage(std::string name);
    GLuint LoadImage(std::string name, const int min, const int mag, const int wrapx, const int wrapy);
    GLuint LoadImage(std::string name, unsigned int& width, unsigned int& height);
    unsigned char* LoadImageData(std::string name, unsigned int& width, unsigned int& height);
    class ImagePrivate
    {
        static ILuint DevilLoadImage(std::string name);
        friend GLuint LoadImage(std::string name);
        friend GLuint LoadImage(std::string name, const int min, const int mag, const int wrapx, const int wrapy);
        friend GLuint LoadImage(std::string name, unsigned int& width, unsigned int& height);
        friend unsigned char*  LoadImageData(std::string name, unsigned int& width, unsigned int& height, unsigned int& bpp);
    };
}
```

The friend methods use the ImagePrivate::DevilLoadImage.

If you already have a namespace (Image), why would you create a class? I thought a class is used for creating objects, but in this case, no objects are created.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can't pass a namespace as a template parameter for example... A namespace is more a static concept (compile-time) than a class which has some kind of existence as a virtual table.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Only polymorphic classes "have some kind of existence" as run-time metadata. This class isn't polymorphic.

Answer (score 0):

> If you already have a namespace (Image), why would you create a class?

It looks like it's being done to make `DevilLoadImage` private, so that it can only be called by the "public" functions in the namespace.

Whether that's a sensible thing to do is a matter of taste. Alternatives are to put internal functions in a "details" namespace, hide them in a source file (which might not be an option for templates), or document that they're not for general use.

> I thought a class is used for creating objects

That's the most common use of course. But it also defines a scope (like a namespace) and allows you to specify the accessibility of members (unlike a namespace), so one could use it for that purpose instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Why not creating a namespace inside of the Image namespace? Would that be different?

Comment: @J.PG: A namespace can't have private members. The aim of this code seems to be to prevent the use of `DevilLoadImage` by anything except the specified functions, by making it a private member. For that, you need a class, not a namespace.